# acme/autocert: unable to satisfy acme challenges for domain: no viable challenge type found

Tags: go, https, lets-encrypt, autocert

I trying to obtain a TLS certificate from Let's Encrypt in order to serve content over HTTPS.

After I run the code on the server in the VM instance on GCP, and tried to connect to it from my browser, the following error message is shown
acme/autocert: unable to satisfy "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/..." for domain "www.mydomain.com": no viable challenge type found

Then I followed the acme-v02.api link shown in the terminal, and the following is shown:

```
{
  "identifier": {
    "type": "dns",
    "value": "www.mydomain.com"
  },
  "status": "deactivated",
  "expires": "2022-06-01T12:37:05Z",
  "challenges": [
    {
      "type": "http-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/...",
      "token": "..."
    },
    {
      "type": "dns-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/...",
      "token": "..."
    },
    {
      "type": "tls-alpn-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/...",
      "token": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: the ... is used to obscure the values as I don't think the information is necessary to solve the problem. Please let me know if they are needed.

Comment: I realized that the problem lies in somehow autocert deactivated the authorization. So now the problem is to figure out how to activate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have configured a redirect from my domain name to my server by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I realized my DNS server didn't have a [CAA record](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/caa/) entry for my host that would have allowed Let's Encrypt. I could have sworn I used to have it as my setup had worked last year. But either I made a mistake or my DNS service lost track of that record. Whatever the cause, the error message wasn't very helpful. Also, from what I see online, there are many other causes for this same failure so take my solution with a grain of salt.

Comment: Hmm adding a CAA record didnt help me, I have same problem as OP... any other suggestions?

Comment: Another problem I had, but can't attest to receiving the same error message at the time, was my firewall was too restrictive. When I disabled the firewall for a minute and reran the certificate acquisition, the challenges got through. Then I enabled the firewall again. I had a firewall running where certain IP address ranges were blocked because of the number of bogus ssh attempts and other port probing that was going on. I think some of those disabled port ranges matched some server farms that Let's Encrypt also used for its challenges.